# How to dynamically display loop items in tables?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, html-table

The following is the design.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Project Title</td>
<td>Download Link</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><asp:Label ID="dlLbl" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
<td><asp:Label ID="dlLink" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And the following is the backend codes.

```
foreach (SPListItem objInnovationListItem in objInnovationList.Items)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(objInnovationListItem["Innovation Approval Status"])== status)
            {
                countStatus++;

                //Displays name of the document and download link
                dlLbl.Text = objInnovationListItem["Project Title"].ToString();
                dlLink.Text = "<a href='/RIDepartment/Innovation%20Submission/" + objInnovationListItem.File.Name + "'>Download</a><br>";
            }
        }
```

Hence, my question is, what can I do to allow the tables to dynamically accommodate the document and dl link when there's more than 1 in the loop?

Appreciate some code samples.

Comment: Try looking into an ASP:Repeater - that should do what you need it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code style (manual creating html without web-controls) i recommend you to look on [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) side. But i can answer to your question:

First - you need to use asp:Repeater like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Project Title</td>
        <td>Download Link</td>
    </tr>
    <asp:Repeater ID="repLinks" runat="server" 
        onitemdatabound="repLinks_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblProject" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlLink" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

second: you need to initialize your collection, that you want to display. For example: you want to display a collection of objInnovationListItem class:

```
public class objInnovationListItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Title;
        }
    }
```

you need do next:

```
        // list - it's source List<objInnovationListItem>
        var bindList = list.Where(p => objInnovationListItem["Innovation Approval Status"] == status); // filter your collection - replace you foreach and if statement

        repLinks.DataSource = bindList; // set to repeater your displayed collection
        repLinks.DataBind(); // bind your collection
```

and last - you need to indicate in your Repeater ItemTemplate  how to display your objInnovationListItem instance - subscribe to event of your Repeater ItemDataBound:

```
        protected void repLinks_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.Item.DataItem as objInnovationListItem;
        ((Label) e.Item.FindControl("lblProject")).Text = item.Name;
        ((HyperLink) e.Item.FindControl("hlLink")).NavigateUrl = string.Format("/downloaduri?id={0}", item.Title);
    }
```

Result will look like that:

[image: Result]

Comment: Hi, may i ask. Where do i place the 3rd part of the code? thanks

Comment: and reports the following error Error 1 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: 3rd part od the code you must place than, where you want to bind your collection. Its can be anywhere - on your Form_Load event, or on Button_Click event.

Comment: About 'Where' - Where its part of LINQ. LINQ is avialable from c# 3.0 and .NET Framework 3.0. To use LINQ you need to inclue next directive "using System.Linq;" on begin of your code file.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a repeater... Something like this  (code might not be exact):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Project Title</td>
        <td>Download Link</td>
    </tr>
    <asp:Repeater id="rptItems" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="dlLbl" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                <td><a href="/RIDepartment/Innovation%20Submission/<%# Eval("File").Name %>">Download</a><br></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

and then in the ItemDataBound event of the repeater, do something like this:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {


            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("dlLbl")).Text= ((SPListItem)e.Item.DataItem)["Project Title"].ToString();

      }
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you skip the server side controls, and just write the actual html?

Include this div in your aspx file:

```
    <div runat="server" id="divTable"></div>
```

And put this in your Page_Load():

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<table><tr><td>Project Title</td><td>Download Link</td></tr>");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("<tr><td>{0}</td><td><a href='{1}'>{1}</a></td></tr>", "Title", "Link");
    }
    sb.Append("</table>");
    divTable.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
```

You'll of course need to replace "Title" and "Link" with the appropriate values.

Your other options is to actually create new labels and links, but ASP.net is notoriously difficult to work with when you create your server side controls dynamically.

Comment: I assume you mean generate the HTML problematically and then pump that into something like and asp:Literal...

Comment: ASP.NET is not difficult to work with creating server side controls dynamically... Why would you even go this route? Just use a repeater/gridview template and do it like how you should be doing it when using .NET. It's counter intuitive to do this since obviously the Title/Link values wil be changing per iteration.

Comment: You reinvent the wheel. Do not even use DataControls such as repeater its possible to use a standart server side controls without dinamic generate html.